# Saving Excel File as Read Only (Interop.Excel) C#

Tags: c#, excel, object

All,

I have the below code which opens a specified excel file deletes the first row and then saves it as a specified CSV.

However when it saves the CSV down it saves it in a read-only format. Can anyone advise how I would ensure the file is not saved down in read only format.

**EDIT** 
I have tried; 
    To set the ReadOnly property to false.

I also am aware two instances of Excel may be opening which may cause the read only status from googling previous posts however including `myApp.Quit()`
 I believe it would close all instances of excel.

```
        public void DeleteRows(string OriginalFileName,String NewFileName)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application myApp;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook myWorkBook;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet myWorkSheet;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range;
        myApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        myWorkBook = myApp.Workbooks.Open(OriginalFileName, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
        myWorkSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)myWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
        range = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)myWorkSheet.Application.Rows[1, Type.Missing];
        range.Select();
        range.Delete(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlDirection.xlUp);
        myApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
        myWorkSheet.SaveAs(NewFileName, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, true, false, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
        myWorkBook.Close(true);
        myApp.Quit();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Excel forces ReadOnly with no Edit Priveledges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41579105/c-sharp-excel-forces-readonly-with-no-edit-priveledges)

Comment: How do you mean the CSV is read only?

Comment: When the user tries to edit the file after the code has run, the CSV is in read only format

Comment: There is no such thing as "read only csv format"; it's plain text without any special features. But Excel does have a tendency to keep files locked while they're open in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set ReadOnlyRecommended as false while saving the excel file.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to change `myWorkBook.Close(true);` to `myWorkBook.Close(false);`